# Code to check when was the last time user opened app

Tags: android

I am sure we all have seen apps that, after a period of days without opening, throw a notification gently reminding the user to use the app again.

I am looking for ways to accomplish this. At the moment, what I have in mind is the following:

- User exists app
- App launches an alarm, that would be activated, for example in 3 days
- App also writes in SharedPreference timestamp of when the alarm was created
- If user opens app before alarm goes off, then app checks for the SharedPreference timestamp and if it's before three days, then it cancels the alarm
- If user does not open app in three days, then alarm is goes off.

What do you guys think of my idea? Is there any better or cleaner one?

Comment: onuserleavehint method called when u press home button of your app, you can store current tiome in  prefrences.

Answer (score 0):

1. When user launches App, cancel pending alarm (if exists) and set one for X days in the future.
2. If user does not launch App again within X days, alarm goes off.

BTW - I would not like any App to behave like this.

Comment: That are many many apps that behave like this.
I would obviously give the user the chance to cancel notifications if he likes. To be honest, I for one dont like the notifications as well. But I am trying to come up with ways to have my users engaged and using the app

Comment: I know, but the best way  to have your users beeing engaged and using your app is ... to give them a great app!  ;-)

Comment: Easier said than done. My game is a casual game, not something that makes the user log in every day because he had to wait for 24 hours for champion to upgrade (clash of clans for example). Trying to figure out ways to get them coming back.